# React Native Transform with key of "perspective" cannot be zero: {"perspective":0}

Tags: animation, react-native, transform

https://rnplay.org/apps/pBrrUg

Here is an error: Transform with key of "perspective" cannot be zero: {"perspective":0}

I modify to not zero ,like 2000, the transform effect doesn't show

What can I do ? thank you !

Comment: solved it myself ! https://rnplay.org/apps/pBrrUg

Comment: how did you fix this ?

Comment: @monssef rnplay is dead， see：https://sketch.expo.io/HJYvJKI3l